# SQL Adding the same char into multiple fields

Tags: sql, teradata

I have an SQL query that brings back 17 numbers with this format

> 06037-11

I need to add a 0 before the dash, so it is:

> 060370-11

Is there an easy way to do this?  I have seen STUFF() as an option, but I don't understand it.

**Edit**
I am using Teradata

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? String manipulation syntax varies.

Comment: Teradata, I have made an edit in my question to relect this answer

Comment: What version of Teradata?

Comment: The version we are using is 14.00.02.05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous response includes example for Teradata 14.x using regular expression support. The following will work in Teradata 13.x or Teradata 12.x without regular expression support:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('06037-11' FROM 1 FOR (POSITION('-' IN '06037-11') -1))
    || '0-'
    || SUBSTRING('06037-11' FROM (POSITION('-' IN '06037-11') + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way in Oracle:

```
with qry as
  (select '06037-11' code from dual)
select regexp_replace(code, '-', '0-') from qry;
```

Comment: This will work in Teradata 14.x now that it supports similar regular expression functions. (+1)

Comment: Running in Teradata I am returned a Parse Error

Answer (score 0):

since you talk about `STUFF` I assue you use SQL Server:

```
select stuff(your_column, charindex('-', your_column), 0, '0')
from your_table
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31836)